# covariance matrix with parameters to guarantee independency?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence, covariance, gaussian

Suppose we have two gaussian vectors $W$ and $Z$ such that their covariance matrix is
$C_{W,Z}$=$$\begin{bmatrix}
    4 & \alpha-1  \\
     \alpha-1 & 1  
    \\\end{bmatrix}
$$

the question is find alpha so that $W$ and $Z$ are independent. Do I just replace $\alpha$ with 1 so that $\operatorname{cov}(W,Z)$=0? Am I allowed to do that? Because I can't think of any other way to solve it but we know that if $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=0$ it doesn't necessarily mean that $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Comment: If $W$ and $Z$ are Gaussian rv's with $\text{cov}(W,Z)=0$ then $W$ and $Z$ are independent. Think about how the joint density of $(W,Z)$ would look like.

Comment: As @MatthewPilling pointed out, the key observation is that Gaussian r.v. have covariance = 0 iff they are independent.

Comment: @Gregory can we generalize that? Does it have to be a Gaussian r.v? or if any covariance matrix is diagonal then its elements are independent?

Comment: If the vector $(W,Z)$ is Gaussian, then $W$ and $Z$ are independent if and only if they are uncorrelated. This is not the case for distributions other than Gaussian. There is also the subtle point that one can have two uncorrelated Gaussian random variables $X$ and $Y$ which are dependent (for example, if $X\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$, $U$ is $\pm1$ with equal probability and is independent of $X$, and $Y=UX$). In this case, the vector $(X,Y)$ is *not* Gaussian.

Comment: @Jason thank you for illuminating me regarding this subtlety